# Remove blank space around scatter graph in core plot

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, scatter-plot

[image]

I'm using core plot for line graph.in the scatter graph i'm getting some blank space around the scatter graph.as you can see the screen shot(in debug mode) my graph plot area is covered by empty space.How can i remove it?

Initialising host view

```
self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height-10)];
self.hostView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];;
self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = NO;
[self addSubview:self.hostView];
```

Initializing graph

```
graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme]];
self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
```

**EDIT**

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.PaddingLeft = 55.0f;
graph.plotAreaFrame.PaddingRight = 15.0f;
graph.plotAreaFrame.PaddingTop = 10.0f;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 28.0;
```

These are the paddings i have provided.

Comment: What part of that picture is the Core Plot hosting view (the graph will fill the hosting view)? Check the layout of the views and the padding on the various parts of your graph.

Comment: the part between red line and red square is the extra space i'm getting.I'll update the paddings given in question.

Comment: Where is the border of the hosting view/graph? Do you have padding on the graph, too? The graph starts with 20 pixels of padding on each edge.

Comment: @EricSkroch I'm not setting any padding for graph any where.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/23846916/2265218 following this link you can get my code .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph starts with 20 pixels of padding on each edge but that's easy to change:

```
graph.PaddingLeft = 0.0;
graph.PaddingTop = 0.0;
graph.PaddingRight = 0.0;
graph.PaddingBottom = 0.0;
```