# how to fix scatter graph size fixed in core plot

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot, scatter-plot

I'm using core plot scatter graph,but i'm not able to maintain size of the.
For some values the graph works fine ,but for some values the size of the graph changes.

Can i fix it using `xRange` ,if yes, how?

please refer these images

1.[image]

2[image]

Why this is happening ?

Comment: Some values of what? What version of Core Plot are you using? Please post your graph setup code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I have downloaded core plot from github.Values are changing but i'm sending two arrays of size 2 and for 2nd pic array size is 3.I'm expecting the width of the graph should not change.

Comment: @EricSkroch here is the link for my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8oqrc562tznhog/Scatter%20Graph.zip

Comment: @[5623006,5532294.1]@[5623006,2867632.07] First Data
@[3327516,3273835.67,3217689.28,3158963.54],@[3327516,2262330.67,1153748.06,0.06]Second data

Comment: Is the size of the hosting view the same each time? I can't tell from the picture whether your hosting view is too small or the graph is compressed. Also check that `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` always returns the count that you expect.

Comment: @EricSkroch No it's not hosting view size as the red border is the hosting view size.It have created a red border around it to confirm the same.And -numberOfRecordsForPlot: ,how does it matters for the graph size?Can you give me some idea,so that i can verify it.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([[mXaxisArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.floatValue"]floatValue])];
```

Added `xRange` to fix this issue